# SSL error after "download" call from yfinance

Tags: python, ssl, yfinance

I installed yfinance in Spyder (Python 3.7) but when I make a basic call, such as:

```
import yfinance as yf


df_yahoo = yf.download('AAPL', 
                       start='2000-01-01', 
                       end='2010-12-31',
                       progress=False)

print(df_yahoo)
```

I get an error message:

> Exception in thread Thread-9: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 672, in urlopen
> chunked=chunked,   File "c:\users/miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 376, in _make_request
> self._validate_conn(conn)   File "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 994, in *validate_conn
> conn.connect()   File "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
> line 360, in connect
> ssl_context=context,   File "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py",
> line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket
> return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)   File "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in
> wrap_socket
> session=session   File "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
> self.do_handshake()   File "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed
> certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
> line 449, in send
> timeout=timeout   File "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 720, in urlopen
> method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]   File
> "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py",
> line 436, in increment
> raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='query1.finance.yahoo.com', port=443): Max
> retries exceeded with url:
> /v8/finance/chart/AAPL?period1=946681200&period2=1293750000&interval=1d&includePrePost=False&events=div%2Csplits
> (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
> CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed
> certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)')))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926, in
> _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()   File "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self.*kwargs)   File "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\multitasking_*init**.py",
> line 102, in _run_via_pool
> return callee(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py",
> line 167, in _download_one_threaded
> actions, period, interval, prepost, proxy, rounding)   File "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py",
> line 182, in _download_one
> rounding=rounding, many=True)   File "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\yfinance\base.py",
> line 150, in history
> data = _requests.get(url=url, params=params, proxies=proxy)   File "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
> line 76, in get
> return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)   File "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
> line 61, in request
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 530, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 643, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "c:\users\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
> line 514, in send
> raise SSLError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='query1.finance.yahoo.com', port=443): Max
> retries exceeded with url:
> /v8/finance/chart/AAPL?period1=946681200&period2=1293750000&interval=1d&includePrePost=False&events=div%2Csplits
> (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
> CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed
> certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)')))

Moreover, Spyder seems to get stuck in some sort of loop and I have to manually interrupt it.

Can anyone help me here?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem comes from an external source, maybe Yahoo Finance was down? I tried running your code and it works fine for me. (PyCharm, Python 3.7)

Comment: in my case it seems to be related to the network in my office. at home it works fine

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS Big Sur, You need to install the certificate in Python 3.9.

```
cd /Applications/Python\ 3.9/
./Install\ Certificates.command
```